# Friends of a user + mutual friend test with another user

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table that I use (but not only) for storing friends in a database :

```
user_1 | user_2 | status
```

where 'status' can be -1,0 or 1. Here, we will consider only cases where status are '0' (pending for user_1) or '1' (approved by user_2). I have the following query to look for pending/approved friends for a given $user :

```
SELECT user_1,user_2,status
         FROM Friends
         WHERE (user_2 = '$user' OR user_1 = '$user') AND status >= 0;
```

The goal here is to modify the query to also tell if a given $user2 is a common (approved) friend of $user1 and each (approved) friend of $user1.

After some researches, I figured out that the left join would do the trick, by setting another field to either NULL (if no mutual) or $user2. I would want to do it efficiently. I tried several shots, but no success around it.

Thanks by advance for your help

EDIT : For example, let's say we have the following entries :

```
a | b | 1
c | a | 1
c | b | 1
a | d | 1
```

I want to list the friends of 'a' and for each friend f of 'a', verify if 'b' is a common friend of f and 'a'. Also, f =/= b for the mutual test. The result of such a query would be :

```
a | b | 1 | NULL
c | a | 1 | b
a | d | 1 | NULL
```

Let me know if you need more clarification

Comment: I don't get it :-) What would you like to get? Maybe some short example?

Comment: and where is `c | a | 1 | d` ? I wouldn't do that in MySQL, but in PHP or whatever language you are using... MySQL will be slow in bigger data sets.

Comment: The 4th field shoult only test the mutual friendship with 'b', that's why the line you suggets shouldn't appears. Another possibility would be indeed to do that in PHP and launch a query per entry to test the mutual friendship with 'b'. But I was afraid that sending multiples query this way would be slower that only send a single query with a left join. But maybe you're right about it, I would be glad to see some similar benchmarks about this

Comment: and what do you expect when there are more mutual friends?

Comment: I expect these to be ignored. Truly, the human-friendly query would be : "Find all friends of 'a' and for each friend 'f' of 'a' check if 'b' is a common friend (i.e., 'f' is also a friend of b)". However, I do not exclude that my approach may be wrong to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in MySQL query would be so complicated and slow, that I wouldn't use it myself, here's a solution in PHP, with only one query:

```
<?php

// $db = mysqli_connect(...);

function findMutualFriends($of,$mutual_with){
    global $db;
    $user_friends = array();
    $mutual_friends = array();
    $results = array();

    $res = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT user_1,user_2,status FROM Friends WHERE ((user_2 = '$of' OR user_1 = '$of') OR (user_2 = '$mutual_with' OR user_1 = '$mutual_with')) AND status >= 0;";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        if($row['user_1'] == $of || $row['user_2'] == $of){
            $user_friends[] = (($row['user_1'] == $of) ? $row['user_2'] : $row['user_1']);
        }
        if($row['user_1'] == $mutual_with || $row['user_2'] == $mutual_with){
            $mutual_friends[(($row['user_1'] == $mutual_with) ? $row['user_2'] : $row['user_1'])] = 1;
        }
    }
    foreach($user_friends as $friend){
        if($mutual_firends[$friend]){
            $results[] = $friend;
        }
    }
    return $results;
}

?>
```

Please notice that it haven't been tested. May contain some minor syntax error, but should return an array of mutual friends.

Comment: Indeed, this is a very good alternative :) thanks for help ! I'll let you know as soon as I it will be tested.

Answer (score 1):

I modified a bit the Flash Thunder's function post. Just tested with some modifications and it works ! Thanks again.

```
function findMutualFriends($pdo, $of,$mutual_with){

    $user_friends = array();
    $mutual_friends = array();
    $results = array();

    $query = "SELECT user_1,user_2,status FROM Friends WHERE ((user_2 = '$of' OR user_1 = '$of') OR (user_2 = '$mutual_with' OR user_1 = '$mutual_with')) AND status = 1;";
    $prep = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $res = $prep->execute();
    $rows = $prep->fetchAll();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if($row['user_1'] == $of || $row['user_2'] == $of) {
            $user_friends[] = ($row['user_1'] == $of ? $row['user_2'] :$row['user_1']);
        }
        if($row['user_1'] == $mutual_with || $row['user_2'] == $mutual_with) {
            $mutual_friends[($row['user_1'] == $mutual_with ? $row['user_2'] :$row['user_1'])] = true;
        }
    }

    foreach($user_friends as $friend) {
        $results[$friend] = $mutual_friends[$friend] == true ? true : false;
    }
    return $results; 
}
```